# System Calls in Perl

Tags: perl, gnu, system-calls, bc

```
$i = system(bc 110^151%14351);
print($i);
```

Hey everyone, I am attempting to use a system call to use a calculator installed on my linux machine. The calculators name is GNU bc, for the basic calculator. Basically it is an easy way to calculate equations. I can easily run it from the terminal by just typing bc and then the function I want to equate, in this case 110 raised to 151 modded by 14351. The problem is, I don't know too much about perl and I keep getting this error Can't call method "bc" without a package or object reference when trying to write a perl script to automate it. How do I call a system call in Perl, or am I allowed to do it? Thanks

Comment: The term "system call" usually refers to a call into the OS kernel, like `read`, `write`, or `ioctl`. A call to the `system` function, confusingly, is not a "system call".

Comment: Why use `system` and `bc` when you can just calculate that in Perl instead? You forgot to put quotes around your system call, and you should use backticks or `qx()` if you want to capture output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using both Perl's `system()` function and the `bc` command

You can get `bc` to do what you want from the command line like this:

```
$ echo '110^151%14351' | bc
7355
```

Perl's `system` function returns a number containing information about the termination status of the invoked command; you want the command's output instead.

To invoke this from Perl, this should work:

```
chomp($i = `echo '110^151%14351' | bc`)
```

The `chomp` is needed because the Perl backticks retain the trailing newline from the command's output.

But you can do this in Perl itself using the `Math::BigInt` package. Type

```
perldoc Math::BigInt
```

at your shell prompt for more information.

Comment: Thanks that taught me a lot about different calls.

Comment: What is the difference between `` and ''?

Comment: @wheatfairies: `perldoc perlop` and search for "Quote and Quote-like Operators".